# Como passo o valor string certo para meu controller? da erro ao retornar para View de Editar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

```
 **// Tentei destas duas formas e não consegui nenhuma!**
   // Onde tem item.nome é de um foreach que me retorna nome de uma pessoa



 <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'><a onclick='funcaoEditar(" + item.nome + ")'><i class='fa fa-pencil text-success'></i></a></span>                           

                                             OU

 <a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='' data-original-title='Editar Unidade' href='/Operador/ProcessoDesenvolvimento/EditarInstrutor?nome=" + item.nome + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil text-success'></i></a>
```

**//Controller**

```
[HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult EditarInstrutor(string nome)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

**//Função Jquery**

```
function funcaoEditar(nome) {
    alert(nome);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditarInstrutor", "ProcessoDesenvolvimento")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ nome: nome }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
}
```

Comment: Qual erro que dá?

Comment: recurso não encontrado

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, vc está fazendo um POST ou um Get? pelo que eu entendi, o Ajax, é um post, mas a Action que recebe é um GET?

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu  alert(nome) esteja retornando o nome certo e você deseje fazer uma alteração, ou seja, um 'PUT'.

Seu controller:

```
[HttpPut] 
    public JsonResult EditarInstrutor(string nome)
    {

      return Json("Dados alterado com sucesso!!");
    }
```

Seu JS:

```
function funcaoEditar(nome) {
    //alert(nome);
   var dados = { nome: nome}; //parametro a ser passado pro controller
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "PUT", // tipo do verbo
        url: "/EditarInstrutor/EditarInstrutor", //nome do controlador e action
        dataType: "json", //tipo de retorno
        data: dados, //paramentros
        success: function (data) {
          //faça algo se tudo for bem sucedido
          },
        error: function (request, status, erro) { 
           //faça algo se der erro
          },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //colocar aqui algo que deseja que faça ao terminar todo o processo              
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere sua Controller para usar o método Post:

```cs
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult EditarInstrutor(string nome)
    {

        return View();
    }
```